# How to configure spring boot application to use SSL/TLS over mariadb?

Tags: spring-boot, mariadb

Connection string

```
    url: jdbc:mariadb://xyz:3306/test?useSSL=true&trustStore=classpath:/path/truststore.jks&trustStorePassword=mypwd&keystoreStore=classpath:/path/keystore.jks&keystoreStorePassword=mypwd
```

when i connect mairadb with tls/ssl connection getting this error
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

how to connect ssl connection using mariadb in spring boot